# Having to Datepicker at the same time with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter, xhtml, twitter-bootstrap

When I try to have 2 datepickers only the first one pops up.
The other one doesn't
I uploaded the code to 
http://jsfiddle.net/2ed8T/

```
<link href="http://aymkdn.github.com/Datepicker-for-Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://github-proxy.kodono.info/?q=https://raw.github.com/Aymkdn/Datepicker-for-Bootstrap/master/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="input-append date" id="dp2" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span2"  name="date_to" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" readonly>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span2"  name="date_to" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" readonly>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>

<script src="http://aymkdn.github.com/Datepicker-for-Bootstrap/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://github-proxy.kodono.info/?q=https://raw.github.com/Aymkdn/Datepicker-for-Bootstrap/master/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>



<script>        
    $(function(){  
        $('#dp2').datepicker()({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
        });
        $('#dp3').datepicker()({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
        });


    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra set of parenthesis in your `.datepicker()` calls.

Instead of `$('#dp2').datepicker()({...})`, it should be `$('#dp2').datepicker({...})`